How macOS Monterey install newest version of motor package for python?
My python project cannot work because of the motor package's version is 2.3.0 and only version up to 3.3.1 can work. I tried download .wl and sudo pip install these higher versions but they could't work. I guess the reason is the macOS12 cannot install higher versions of motor.
My mac is air2017, keep in macOS Monterey and cannot upgrade the system anymore.
the question sames to those packages like ipython, aiohttp, aiomysql.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

After I update my python to 3.12, changed my miniconda source, I can install all the package I cannot install before. Thanks for reply.

You're likely running an older version of Python. You can download a newer version from here. I would recommend the latest stable version 3.12. After running the package installer, you can then install the latest version of a package with
python3.12 -m pip install motor

or a specific version with
python3.12 -m pip install motor==3.3.1

I was able to install motor 3.4.0 and 3.3.1 on an even older version of macOS-Big Sur. Just remember to run your program using the same Python version.
If that doesn't work, you can always download the source directly (either from that same page, or the GitHub) and then either add that to your system path or work inside the directory for a quick test.
